# Why can I pass an Integer when a param of type Long is expected?

Tags: .net, vb.net, interop

I have an adapter class around a native code dll. That one is built in x64 - integer are on 8 bytes. I use the following signature:

```
Private Declare Sub RoutineName64 Lib "MyDll" Alias "_RoutineAlias" (param1 As Long, ... )
```

To my surprise, I can still pass an Integer as param1, without any issue, neither compile time nor runtime. I am not sure how to explain that?

I thought doing `Dim variableLong = Convert.ToInt64(variable)` and then call `RoutineName64` with that variable as `param1` would be mandatory?

Comment: Are you confused because it's native code, or would you expect it to fail with a regular method as well? Basically there's an implicit conversion from `Integer` to `Long`.

Comment: "integer are on 8 bytes".  No, Windows code universally uses the [LLP64 data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models).  So a C function parameter of type int or long stays at 32 bits, `As Integer` required in the declaration to match it.  Such a mismatch is normally fatal in 32-bit mode, it works by accident in x64 because of the way it passes arguments.  Might well be fatal to a future maintainer of this code, the conniption is hard to recover from.

Comment: @HansPassant my Fortran dll explicitely uses Integer KIND 8 representation in x64.

Comment: Well, that's 5 minutes of my life I'll never get back.

Comment: Sorry to read that. Thanks anyway @HansPassant, your answers are always a pleasure to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Widening and Narrowing Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/widening-and-narrowing-conversions).